# I want to remove the ": , PM " in the string "07:08:19PM". I want a result of 07 08 19

Tags: java, java-time

**I am trying to use the split function to remove ": and PM" in the string.**

```
"07:45:19PM"
```

**I want to make 07:45:19PM into 07 45 19**

```
String s = "07:45:19PM"

String heys[] = new String[10];
heys = s.split(":PM");
```

Answer (score 2):

The flexible high-level solution uses java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

For many purposes you should not want to convert a time from one string format to another. In your program, rather keep a time of day as a `LocalTime` object. Just like you keep numbers in `int` or `double` variables, not strings. When you receive a string, parse it into a `LocalTime` first thing. Only when you need to give out a string, format the `LocalTime` into the desired string.

**Parsing input**

```
    DateTimeFormatter givenFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String s = "07:45:19PM";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(s, givenFormatter);
```

**Formatting and printing output**

```
    DateTimeFormatter wantedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh mm ss");
    String wantedString = time.format(wantedFormatter);
    System.out.println(wantedString);
```

Output is:

> 07 45 19

**Tutorial link**

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

`split` accepts a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean), so you need to use `:|PM` to mean "a `:` or `PM`":

```
String[] heys = s.split(":|PM");
```

You don't need to specify the length of `keys` because `split` will figure that out by itself.

Alternatively, if you actually want to extract the hour, minute, and seconds as integers, you can use `LocalTime.parse`:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(s, 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa").withLocale(Locale.US));
int hour = time.getHour();
int minute = time.getMinute();
int second = time.getSecond();
```

Comment: Showing the `LocalTime` solution is good. For hour within AM or PM you need lowercase `hh` in your format pattern string (or parsing will probably fail when you try to parse `12:45:19AM` or `01:45:19PM`).

Comment: Mnemonic: Small `h`is for the small numbers, up to 12. big `H` for the numbers up to 23. The rule works for `d`/`D`and `n`/`N` too, but there are many other examples where it doesn’t. For `m`/`M` you rather need to think of a month as larger than a minute, for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Just simply use this code :**

```
String s = "07:45:19PM";
String[] heys = s.split(":");
for(String hey: heys) {
    System.out.print(hey.replace("PM", "") + " ");
}
```

Output :

```
07 45 19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "07:45:19PM";
String heys[] = s.split(":|PM");
String parsedString = new StringBuilder().append(heys[0]).append(" ").append(heys[1]).append(" ").append(heys[2]).toString();
```